# C# How to capture input from pipeline from continuous stream source

Tags: c#

I have a service that runs as a console app and outputs to stdout and stderr streams to the console.  The developers don't want to add any logging capabilities since it was mainly designed for linux world and they have tools like logroate and other means already but don't care about the windows port.  I want to redirect those streams into a log and I'm able to do it like this:
service.exe 2>&1 >> service.log

But if I leave this running this log will grow out of control.  So I tried using something called logrotateWin but it needs to rename the log file and I get access denied since its in use.  So I'm trying to write another app that can write to logfile and rotate it based once a day and only keep last n logs.

I want to be able to run it like:
service.exe 2>&1 | logrotater.exe

So I'm trying to write logrotater with the following code but it seems to fail to read the stream from the pipeline.  It can read the stream if it stops like from a simple echo "test" command source, but not from service.exe that continuously keeps streaming data out.  Any suggestions?

So this works:
echo "test" | logrotater.exe

But this doesn't work:
service.exe 2>&1 | logrotater.exe

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192))); // This will allow input >256 chars
    while (Console.In.Peek() != -1) {
        string input = Console.In.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Data read was " + input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every major logging framework includes the ability to rotate logs, and they have all figured out how to deal with intricacies of writing files you probably haven't considered. Rather than writing to files directly, I recommend making _your log rotation app_ use a logging library rather than writing to files directly.

Comment: Writing to the file and rotating the logs is the easy part.  I couldn't figure out how to capture the input from the pipeline but using Joel's method below it works.  I don't mind using log4net or other libraries but that doesn't solve my main problem.  Now that Joel's solution works in cmd shell, I'm having trouble getting it to work in Powershell.  It just hangs and no output to console or file when I try something like this in powershell but it works in cmd

service.exe 2>&1 | logrotater.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Log()` method that opens and closes the file as needed. Moving to a separate method will make it easier to isolate these changes from the rest of the program. One easy way to open/close as needed is with `File.AppendAllText()`.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192))); // This will allow input >256 chars

    string input;
    while ( (input= Console.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        Log(input);
    }
}

static void Log(string data)
{
    string msg = $"Data read was {data}";
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
    File.AppendAllText("C:\YourPath", msg);
}
```

Comment: Wow I'm surprised how simple it is and it works!!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @joe, thank you for that.  I have another problem when I try to run it in Powershell.

In CMD works fine:
service.exe 2>&1 | logrotater.exe

In Powershell just hangs and no output to screen or log file as if the stream isn't being captured:
service.exe 2>&1 | logrotater.exe

In Powershell the output goes straight to the console and bypass the logrotator.exe code that you gave me
service.exe | logrotater.exe

How do I get logrotater.exe to capture the output from service.exe the same that it does when using cmd.exe?  I understand powershell treats pipes differently